# Stop looking at this and look up!

Tags: riddle, haiku

> You see me right now
> If you look up from tech and
> Gasp at my beauty
>
> I am everything
> From the tiny to the big
> I'm almost empty

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Space

Reason:

> Looking up could be a reference to the stars in that portion of space.  From a certain view things can be/look small or big and take a volume of space.  I'm almost empty, can refer to all the areas that have no space in comparison to that which takes space.

Comment: I think this is already answered.

Comment: I think someone answered while I was typing, because I only saw one answer,

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait a bit to press the check mark because it was so fast. Still, you did it! YAY!!

Comment: Actually, I like your explanation better. :)

Comment: Hey @You you're supposed to accept the first correct answer

Comment: But I'm the one who choses the correct answers, right? And part of a correct answer is a good explanation.

Comment: @You generally you accept the first correct answer that gives a correct explanation. You told me YAY you did it! Which to me means that I have got the correct explanation. Please tell me next time when me explanation isn't sufficient so that I can edit it to make it so and get the accept-ion.

Comment: So now I just move the correct answer over to you?

Comment: @You no not for this question but in the future please bear this in mind

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it is not necessary for the question poser to accept the first correct answer. He can accept whichever he want to accept. For more info. see [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3267/is-first-answer-a-valid-reason-to-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Space

Because:

> Can be both outer space or an empty place.

Comment: You did it too! YAY!!

Answer (score 3):

> The universe

Reasoning:

> Wherever we look we are seeing the universe because we are *in* it. The universe to us is everything from the tiny to the big and it is full of dark matter - emptiness.

Comment: You did it! YAY!!

Comment: another answer could be space

Comment: @manshu Space and the universe are basically the same thing.

Comment: @You I'm afraid you are very wrong there but for the purpose of this puzzle either could be true

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Well, I meant outer space, but yeah. They are different.

Answer (score 2):

I had a moment of inspiration and thought of an another possible answer:

> A shadow

Reason:

> If you look up you realize everything has a shadow even the phone you may be looking at.  It can be tiny or large, it comes from everything, and it is basically empty.

It could be beautiful, but this is the possible exception to this answer.

Comment: Amazing false positive! And a shadow could be beautiful if you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

> Atoms

Reason:

> "Space" (meaning Outer Space as indicated by the asker) is a bad answer.
>  *You see me right now*: I do not see Outer Space right now.
>  *If you look up from tech*: I still do not see Outer Space.
>  *I am everything*: Outer Space is not everything, it is not Earth or people for example.

So:

> Atoms fit every line. And yes they are mostly empty.

Comment: Earth is in outer space, and if you stop looking at your screen you are looking at it (look up). Atoms are a good false positive, though!